# Filtering Wordpress categories in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I'm currently creating a website using Gatsby and querying data from Wordpress using the gatsby-source-wordpress plug-in. In my gatsby-node file I've set things up to dynamically create web pages based on a post's category. When I try to run a query sorting by category slug and filtering by post date, I receive an error: "Error: The result of this StaticQuery could not be fetched."

Can someone take a look at this and let me know where I'm going wrong exactly?

The gatsby-node file:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/blog-post.js')
  const blogCategoryFilter = path.resolve('./src/templates/blog-filter-category.js')

  const res = await graphql(`
      query {
        allWordpressPost {
          edges {
            node {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
        allWordpressCategory {
          edges {
            node {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `)

  res.data.allWordpressPost.edges.forEach((edge) => {
    createPage({
      component: blogPostTemplate,
      path: `/blog/${edge.node.slug}`,
      context: {
        slug: edge.node.slug,
      }
    })
  })

  res.data.allWordpressCategory.edges.forEach((edge) => {
    createPage({
      component: blogCategoryFilter,
      path: `/blog/${edge.node.slug}`,
      context: {
        slug: edge.node.slug,
      }
    })
  })

}
```

The template file I'm using to actually generate the filtered and sorted content (blog-filter-category.js):

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import { Link, graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby'

import BlogNav from '../components/blognav'

import blogStyles from '../components/modules/blog.module.css'



const BlogPage = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    allWordpressCategory (filter: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          name
        }
      }
    }
    allWordpressPost (sort: {fields:date, order:DESC}) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          slug
          content
          date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        }
      }
    }
  }
  `)


  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className={blogStyles.blog_container}>
        <div className={blogStyles.blogContent_container}>
          <ol>
            {data.allWordpressPost.edges.map((edge) => {
              return (
                <div className={blogStyles.blogPost_container}>
                  <li className={blogStyles.blog_list}>
                    <h2><Link to={`/blog/${edge.node.slug}`} className={blogStyles.blog_title} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: edge.node.title }}></Link></h2>
                    <p className={blogStyles.blog_date}>{edge.node.date}</p>
                    <p className={blogStyles.blog_content} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: edge.node.content }} />
                  </li>
                </div>
              )
            })}
          </ol>
        </div>
        <BlogNav />
      </div>

    </Layout>
  )
}

export default BlogPage
```

I also tried querying this instead in my blog-filter-category.js file:

```
  query($slug: String!) {
    allWordpressPost (filter: {categories: {elemMatch: {slug: { eq: $slug }}}}) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          slug
          content
          date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It seemed closer but I ended up netting the same error message. I'm lost! Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on you choice to build with Gatsby.

First problem I see is that you try to use variables in you static queries. This is not possible at the moment. Variable passed to page context are only available in [page queries](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/).

Page queries are defined in page templates as simple exports like:

```
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

export const query = graphql`
  query MyQuery($slug: String!) {
    allWordpressPost (filter: {categories: {elemMatch: {slug: { eq: $slug }}}}) {
      edges {
        node {
        title
        slug
        content
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

Learn more about differences between page and static queries in Gatsby here:
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/#how-staticquery-differs-from-page-query